# firebase recycler adapter is blink when data changes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

A channel was implemented with firebase recycler adapter. Every time the data on the channel changes, channel's cell becomes shiny. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

in your initialize recyclerview

```
((SimpleItemAnimator) myRecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```